# Boot-loop, error code 0xc0000225, after full-drive encryption

Tags: disk-encryption, diagnostic, hard-drive-failure, diskcryptor

I encrypted both my personal and system file drives using ***Diskcryptor***, after full completion I set my laptop to hibernate. Now, my device is stuck in a bootloop with my only option being to use CMD as the drives are locked with no option to enter my pass-key for possible file recovery. There's 2 recovery drive partitions present, although I'm unsure of their content and whether they contain any of the up-to-date files that I need.

I'm running windows 10, however, I don't know which build I'm using, other than, it's the second-to-most recent build, assuming that a new build was released during the period my laptop was in hibernation for (7 days). I was running the most recent release of DiskCryptor, also.

I disabled the automatic boot repair for ease of access, using:

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

Then ran the following commands (with the returns):

```
bootrec /fixmbr ('successful')
bootrec /fixboot ('successful')
bootrec /rebuildbcd ('successful')
```

Checked the state of the encrypted drive in read-only mode:

```
X:\windows\system32>chkdsk
... NTFS 
Volume label is Boot.

Read-only chkdsk found bad on-disk uppercase table - using system table.

(Stage 1 and 2, successful) 

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors . . .
Security descriptor verification completed.
    7 data files processed.

 Errors detected in the uppercase file.

 ... 'found problems'

 Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with event 50.

 X:\windows\system32>chkdsk /f
 The type of file system is NTFS.
 Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected. 

 X:\windows\system32>chkdsk /c /f
 The type of file system is NTFS.
 Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.
```

When attempting to view the file directory of the system volume:

```
 dir c:
 The volume does not contain a recognized file system.
  Please make sure all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is corrupted
```

Whereas;

```
dir d: 
Volume in drive D is SAMSUNG_REC2

dir e:
Volume in drive E is SAMSUNG_REC
```

I don't know what to do and the official website ran by the developer, hasn't been up for a small while. **What are my options?**

I'm happy to provide any system information that you need ASAP. I don't really know what I'm doing, I hope the information above isn't unclear or incorrect - if it is, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for any help that you can provide. It won't go unappreciated!

**Edit**: Here's a summary of the console command sets (I have no clue how to use them):

> https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:78H02mu-KBYJ:https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Console

**Edit 2**: Here's the boot recovery screen,
[Error screen](http://www.imgur.com/9edJ7mY)

**Edit 3**: If I'm understanding the problem correctly: is it that, the location of the files required to boot/run the OS, is within an encrypted partition where they can't be accessed without the passkey? Whereas no option to enter the passkey can be present due to the boot-setup of my system and the location of DiskCryptor's "firmware" cannot be accessed either, due to also being within the encrypted partition. Is that correct?

If so, would it be possible to load the SSHD in a booted system using external or external hardware, where therein I can decrypt the files using my passkey? I'm eager to test any recommendations. Thus being first and only encounter with Diskcryptor and with full-drive encryption, I'm clueless in regard to the whole decryption process, so I may need brief instructions if any of the above are valid options -- please.